# how to display the coordinates of a openlayers map with a jquery in my asp.net textbox?

Tags: openlayers-2, jquery, asp.net

**this is my initmap.js**

```
OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {
defaultHandlerOptions: {
},

initialize: function (options) {
    this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
        {}, this.defaultHandlerOptions
    );
    OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(
        this, arguments
    );
    this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
        this, {
            'click': this.trigger
        }, this.handlerOptions
    );
},

trigger: function (e) {
    var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy).transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:900913");
    alert("You clicked near " + lonlat.lat + " N, " +
                              +lonlat.lon + " E");
    //document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = lonlat.lat;
    //document.getElementById("TextBox2").value = lonlat.lon;

}

});
function init() {
size = new OpenLayers.Size(26, 30);

var mapOptions = {
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
    displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    //units: "m",
    //maxResolution: 156543.0339,
    //numZoomLevels: 18,
    controls: [
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.NavToolbar(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({ 'ascending': false }),
                    //new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
                    //new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink('Refresh'),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap({
                        mapOptions: mapOptions,
                        maximized: true,

                    }),
                ]
};

map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', mapOptions);

nav = new OpenLayers.Control.NavigationHistory();
map.addControl(nav);
panel = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel(
    { div: document.getElementById("panel") }
);
panel.addControls([nav.next, nav.previous]);
map.addControl(panel);


//Ajouter les couche google
var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Physical",
    { type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN }
);
var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Streets", // the default
    {numZoomLevels: 20 }
);
var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Hybrid",
    { type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, numZoomLevels: 20, isBaseLayer: true }
);
var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Satellite",
    { type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, numZoomLevels: 20}
);
map.addLayers([gsat, ghyb, gmap, gphy]);


map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({ div: document.getElementById("LabelCoords"), numDigits: 5, prefix: "", separator: ",", mapOptions: mapOptions }));
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-9.2, 31.9).transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:900913"), 7);
var click = new OpenLayers.Control.Click();
map.addControl(click);
click.activate();

 }
```

Comment: I note that the getCoordsClick function is not running even though I called I want to know why not?

Comment: I want to be sure I understand. When user clicks on map, you want to display coordinates in the textbox called "LabelCoords"? And in place of "show x" and "show y" you want to show real coordinates, for example -12.21 and 31.54 ?

Comment: yes exactely thats what i want to do

Comment: Is this code available to see online?
You can try using Google Chrome, press F12, see "console". http://i.imgur.com/cdQpMMw.png
Do you see any error here, when you click on the map?

Comment: i have some errore but i don understand what to do http://i.imgur.com/Nu8WeJs.jpg

Comment: Is this application available online? It would be much easier to find the problem if it was. Now I am guessing.

Comment: what do you mean about application available online

Comment: Can I see it online?

Comment: i work juste in localhost

Comment: i want send you my inizyalize code for map here but they tele me that i can do that after 8hours

Comment: you can edit your question and add the code there?

Comment: the javascript code how you give me it work but the problem is how can i sent the value of  lonlat.lat and lonlat.lon in my tow asp:textbox?

Comment: See my example, these lines:
document.getElementById("siteX").value = lonlat.lat;
document.getElementById("siteY").value = lonlat.lon;
It should work.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: for this reason i was used jquery beceause it give the possibility to send information from value o javascripte to asp

Comment: see example on my website. It works. http://xerocode.com/gis/Openlayers.html

Comment: Add master.master file too.

Comment: And this, too js/initmap.js :)
I am sleepy and very slow now. Sorry about that.

Comment: im so sorry for that , it does not matter  you can answer me tomorrow if you can :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using OpenLayers click, and not jquery click. Here are examples: [OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/click.html](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/click.html), [getting-the-coordinates-of-a-click-in-openlayers-map/](http://codezone4.wordpress.com/2013/04/06/getting-the-coordinates-of-a-click-in-openlayers-map/)

I created an example and uploaded to my website, it is available here: http://xerocode.com/gis/Openlayers.html

Fragments from my html file. Pay attention to the START/END blocks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/OpenLayers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // START
        OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {                
        defaultHandlerOptions: {
            'single': true,
            'double': false,
            'pixelTolerance': 0,
            'stopSingle': false,
            'stopDouble': false
        },

        initialize: function(options) {
            this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
                {}, this.defaultHandlerOptions
            );
            OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(
                this, arguments
            ); 
            this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
                this, {
                    'click': this.trigger
                }, this.handlerOptions
            );
        }, 

        trigger: function(e){
            var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
            document.getElementById("siteX").value = lonlat.lat;
            document.getElementById("siteY").value = lonlat.lon;
        }

        });
        // END

        var lon = 5;
        var lat = 40;
        var zoom = 5;
        var map, layer;

        function init()
        {
            map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map' );
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer( "OpenLayers WMS", 
                    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'},
                    {gutter: 15});
            map.addLayer(layer);

            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);
            map.addControl( new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher() );

            // START
            var click = new OpenLayers.Control.Click();
            map.addControl(click);
            click.activate();
           // END
        }
    </script>
</head>
 <body onload="init()">
    <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
    <!-- START -->
    <input type="textbox" id="siteX" />
    <input type="textbox" id="siteY" />
    <!-- END -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: after using this code i have after I click on the map I get this http://i.imgur.com/Vjx9wgx.jpg

Comment: I think the function getCoordsClick is not in a state of reading I use a master page it may be its the problem!!!

Comment: @wissam I edited my answer. I don't know your HTML structure. You only showed small part of HTML. But I think problem is conflict between jquery and openlayers. When user clicks in the map, openlayers click event happens.

Comment: it work for <input type="textbox" id="siteX" />             but not for <asp:TextBox ID="siteX" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>   whene i try to call   the inpute in my classe map.aspx.cs it doesnt called

Comment: Edit your question, show map.aspx code. I use ASP.NET at work, don't know why you have a problem. Do you have Iframe in your page?

Comment: you can call your textbox in your classe aspx.cs?